# Организация транзакций с помощью Spring в несколько репозиториев

Tags: java, mysql, spring

Существует несколько репозиториев, в которые необходимо записать данные, в случае неудачи - откатить изменения.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public class PlayerRegistrationController {

GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();

@Autowired
private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

@Autowired
private SessionRepository sessionRepository;

@Autowired
private ResourseRepository resourseRepository;

@Autowired
private PlayerResourseRepository playerResourseRepository;

@Autowired
private PlayerRoomRepository playerRoomRepository;

@Autowired
private PlayerStatsRepository playerStatsRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", produces = { "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<? extends Response> singUp(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String jsonString, BindingResult bindingResult) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    ...

    String sessionId;
    try{
        sessionId = saveSingUpData(player, request);
    } catch (Exception e){
        RegistrationResponse regResponse = new RegistrationResponse((long)2);
        return new ResponseEntity<RegistrationResponse>(regResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<RegistrationResponse>((new RegistrationResponse(((long)0),sessionId)), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Transactional
public String saveSingUpData(Player player, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    playerRepository.save(player);
    player = playerRepository.findByLogin(player.getLogin());
    Session session = new Session(player.getIdPlayer(), request.getSession().getId());
    sessionRepository.save(session);
    List<Resourse> resourse = resourseRepository.findAll();
    for (Resourse i : resourse) {
        PlayerResourse playerResourse = new PlayerResourse(player.getIdPlayer(), i.getIdResourse(), 0, 0);
        if (playerResourse.getResourse() == 1) {
            playerResourse.setValue(10000);
        } else if (playerResourse.getResourse() == 3) {
            playerResourse.setValue(20);
        }
        playerResourseRepository.save(playerResourse);
    }
    PlayerStats playerStats = new PlayerStats(player.getIdPlayer(),request.getRemoteAddr(),(byte)1);
    playerStatsRepository.save(playerStats);
    PlayerRoom playerRoom = new PlayerRoom(player.getIdPlayer(),1, (byte)0, 1);
    playerRoomRepository.save(playerRoom);
    return  session.getSessionId();
}
}
```

Что необходимо добавить/изменить, чтобы аннотация @Transactional работала?

Comment: А, что, так не работает?

Comment: Зачем это всё? Похоже на то, что сущности `Player`, `PlayerResource`, `PlayerStats` и `PlayerRoom` связаны отношениями. Если правильно прописать каскады, то достаточно будет сохранить `Player`, чтобы остальное сохранилось автоматически.

Comment: Есть три способа реализации транзакций, в каждом из них прописывается реализация bean'ов и дополнительных библиотек

Comment: Сущности связаны отношениями - это прописано явно в классе сущностей. В этом примере необходимо сохранить две разные сущности в разные репозитории. Если одно из этих сохранений завершилось ошибкой, должен произойти откат с помощью транзакции.

Comment: @Argetto уточните, что у вас не работает? почему вы решили, что транзакция не откатывается? Согласно вашему коду метод saveSingUpData - транзакционный и при любой SQLException будет ролбэк всех операций в любый репозитории. Или вам нужно чтобы ролбэк был при любой ошибке?